# Term store with variation label not indexed

Tags: 2010, search, managed-metadata, term-store, variations

Our user profiles have a property who values are coming from a term store.

> http:/testSite/**en**/search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k="**cheese**"

This works fine and the results page is populated by users who <s>like</s> love cheese.

The issue now is that we have a French variation in our site and doing a search for "fromage" (Cheese in French), yields no result.

> http:/testSite/**fr**/search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k="**fromage**"

We have "fromage" set as the FR label in our term store so I don't know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The link below explains a similar scenario.

http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/timmy/archive/2011/12/01/mui-managed-metadata-vs-search.aspx

Accordingly:

> it depends on what the default language is of your web.

Therefore please check if the default language of the web is correctly set to french or if it is a multilingual site, then please select the language as mentioned in the link above.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Very informative post there. I have checked and the default language is indeed French, but there are still no search results

Comment: @kei could you please check SPWeb.Locale as well to confirm it is correct. [SPWeb.Locale vs SPWeb.Language](http://spsitelog.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/the-difference-between-spweb-language-and-spweb-locale/)

Comment: You can also set the lanuage on the search page. [Check this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/06/28/multilingual-search-in-sharepoint-server-2010-and-fast-search-server-2010.aspx) out for more information.

Comment: Checked just now using PowerShell. `{LCID:3084, Name:fr-CA, DisplayName:French (Canada)}`

Comment: I've set the language of the search page as well. Still nothing.

Comment: @kei What was the language that you selected when you added a new title for the term in term store. Was it just French or French (Canadian). Can you please change the locale of your web to just French (fr-Fr) and see if the results show up.

Comment: Haven't tested yet, but it seems that this is most likely the cause of the issue. Thanks.